# How to insert character or word N times in a buffer or file?

Tags: insert, text

Just curious to know how to do this, since i already know in other languages (bash, etc).

I know how to insert a character in elisp, just not sure on how to do it when it's done nth time (in succession) in elisp.

Here an example:

Basically, inserting (in file or buffer) the character X, 10 times.

`XXXXXXXXXX` something like that.

Comment: Firstly you do it (N-1) times.  Then you do it one more time.

Comment: Serious comment: I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: My bad, let me try again: basically, you know how you can input/insert a character *once* in "put your language here" right? what i want to do here, is basically that, but more than *once*...as in, i can insert/input X character with a given number of time to input it.

Comment: I already know how to do it in bash and python, but i'm curious about a pure elisp method.

Comment: and lastly, i do know how to insert a character in elisp, but what i don't know (or at least not sure enough)is how to do it but with a specific amount of time. @phils tell me if this clearer btw :)

Comment: Like `(insert (make-string 10 ?X))` ?  Or `(dotimes (_ 10) (insert "X"))` ?

Comment: Yep! works! @phils

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Yeah, seems i did again...my bad @Drew ><

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways to write loops/iterative/repetitive behaviour in elisp.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Iteration` has the basic options, including `dotimes`, which is the canonical way to repeat something N times.  E.g.:

```
(dotimes (_ 10) (insert "X"))
```

For the specific example of repeating a character N times, you might alternatively use `make-string`.

```
(insert (make-string 10 ?X))
```

For more sophisticated looping options, I suggest starting at <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(cl)Iteration`

Comment: help for `dotimes` notes _its use is deprecated_. Is there a more modern substitute?

Comment: It says that using the `RESULT` argument is deprecated, not that `dotimes` is deprecated.

Comment: Oh, so it does! That's good I guess.

Comment: It looks like the only reason they've marked it deprecated is that the macro expansion for handling RESULT has to bind VAR, but VAR might not be used in RESULT, which then produces a byte-compilation warning under lexical binding about VAR not being used.  I feel like this problem could be fixed.  In any case, I don't imagine that functionality is *going away* any time soon, so I wouldn't be too concerned about using it it you need it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to insert the character interactively, do 
`C-u 10 X`.  This will give you `XXXXXXXXXX`.

This repeats the `self-insert-command` (here, for "X"), 10 times.  See the manual node on [repeating](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Repeating.html).